# Не до конца понял принцип работы Layouts

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

Начал изучать андроид разработку, задался множеством вопросов когда узнал о возможности добавления разных типов Layouts в один XML файл, ну или файл макета, как вам удобнее, вопросы возникли к верхней строчке XML файла где присутствует и описан определенный вид Layout например Linear Layout.
Код:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat - вот эта строка вызвала сомнение, я прочитал что это какой-то корневой элемент в языке XML но что он делает и почему ему присваивается имя одного из видов Layout я понять так  и не смог, сначала я думал что это что-то по типу "контейнера" в который кладутся определенные типы Layouts, но покопавшись в дизайне макета, ничего туда положить не смог, я думаю что эта какая-то библиотека или что-то по типу того, но какую из этих "библиотек" использовать, как и с чем, я так и не понял, буду рад если объясните чайнику.

Comment: Учиться, учиться и еще раз учиться: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout

Comment: Можете попробовать начать сразу с Compose, это позволит пропустить изучение XML: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"это что-то по типу "контейнера" в который кладутся определенные типы Layouts" или сами элементы.
Грубо говоря, в Андроид верстке, на экране может быть только 1 элемент. А вы хотите разместить несколько. Как быть?
Вы размещаете на экране единственный элемент - нужный вам Layout. И уже в него кладете (ложите) необходимые элементы.

Пустая XML, без корневого элемента - это ваш мольберт.
Корневой элемент - это холст. Холст должен стоять на мольберте.
Ваши View для UI - ваше изображение. вы должны рисовать их на холсте.

Все автоматические приписки типа `xmlns:android=` - это то, что делает ваш холст холстом, а не просто куском дерева с тканью.

Comment: Большое спасибо, я наконец-таки понял, очень доступное объяснение.